# Get Documentsets in the sharepoint Library- CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I need to Get the details of the Documentsets in the Library using CSOM. I cannot use the ContenttypeID, with out ContentTypeId i need to get the documentset details.

Need help on this
Thanks,